# How to copy row from a table to another table if the entry is not exist in the new table in sql

Tags: sql, copy

I need to copy all data from a table to an another same schema table. If the new table has a row already then i need not to update or insert it. I need only new data from old table that does not exist in new table to copy to that new table.

So what will be the sql query, can any one help me.

Thanks,
Muntasir Rahman Rafi

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly).... also: please **SHOW US** the table structures!

Comment: sometimes people call Microsof'ts SSMS (SQL Server management server) just "SQL" we do it all the time where I work

Comment: technically, the language that SSMS uses to implement SQL is called TSQL, but again we very rarely use that usage where I work

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try this :

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME2 (col1, Col2, col3)
SELECT *
FROM tablename1 A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT *
          FROM tablename2 B
          WHERE A.col1 = B.col1
     )
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this one -

```
INSERT INTO new_table(...)
SELECT *
FROM old_table AS o
WHERE o.ID NOT IN (
     SELECT n.ID FROM new_table AS n
)
```

Or this -

```
INSERT INTO new_table(...)
SELECT o.*
FROM old_table AS o
LEFT JOIN new_table AS n ON n.ID = o.ID
WHERE n.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: The second version will fail. you are using `SELECT *` you should use `SELECT o.*`

Comment: It returns rows exist in both table if they are exist