# Insert data from one database to another database if record does not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been searching for a couple of days and couldn't find a way to copy data from 1 database to another database.

I've referred to [Copy tables from one database to another in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187770/copy-tables-from-one-database-to-another-in-sql-server)
 and [How to copy row from a table to another table if the entry does not exist in the new table in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540598/how-to-copy-row-from-a-table-to-another-table-if-the-entry-is-not-exist-in-the-n) - come out with some query and it showed [0 rows affected] (I've created some dummy records only in Source database to see if it is working)

Query as below:-
[Column1 and Column2 are primary keys, Column1 can be the same but column2 has to be different]

```
USE Destination
INSERT INTO Destination.dbo.Table(Column1, Column2, Column3 etc...)
SELECT * FROM Source.dbo.Table(Column1, Column2, Column3 etc...) 
WHERE Source.dbo.Table.Column1= Column1 And Source.dbo.Table.Column2 Not In (Column2)
```

Appreciate if anyone can let me know what's wrong with the query / any similar question(s) I missed out to refer to / any method can work the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try to use `exists` and `not exists` to make it.

```
USE Destination
INSERT INTO Destination.dbo.Table(Column1, Column2, Column3 etc...)
SELECT t1.Column1, t1.Column2, t1.Column3 etc... 
FROM Source.dbo.Table t1
WHERE   
     exists (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Destination.dbo.Table t2
        WHERE t2.Column1  = t1.Column1
     )
And 
    not exists (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Destination.dbo.Table t2
        WHERE t2.Column2  = t1.Column2
     )
```

Comment: Cool, it is working now
Thank you so much for your help.